# Contract Name Types in Truffle Solidity Tests

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

The example in the [docs](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/solidity-tests) for truffle .sol tests has these lines:

`MetaCoin meta = MetaCoin(DeployedAddresses.MetaCoin());`

and

`MetaCoin meta = new MetaCoin();`

I've had a good read through the docs and don't understand why the MetaCoin type shows up so often. Wouldn't it be easier to access the deployed address with:

`var meta = DeployedAddresses.MetaCoin();` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a state variable `meta` cast as Type `MetaCoin`. The compiler understands this Type by seeing the `.sol` code for `MetaCoin`, so `meta` gets all the methods of a `MetaCoin` contract.

You would accomplish that much with:

```
MetaCoin meta;
```

To be meaningful, it needs an address. Maybe it's already published, so a contract that wants to talk to it could get situated using an address passed to the constuctor.

```
   function MyContract(address metaAddress) {
      meta = MetaCoin(metaAddress);
   }
```

This is allowed, because `meta` is a `MetaCoin` - both sides are cast as the same Type.

Or, maybe you want to deploy a new MetaCoin each time:

```
function newMetaCoin() returns(address newContract)
    meta = new MetaCoin();
    return(meta);
}
```

The `return` works because contracts are directly convertable to Type `address`. It's shorthand for `return(address(meta));`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

[MetaCoin](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle-webpack-demo/blob/master/contracts/MetaCoin.sol) is simply what the truffle framework uses for demo purposes. Note how the contract is defined under the `truffle-webpack-demo` repository.

In order for you to interact with any of the functions defined in that contract (i.e. `sendCoin`), you need to instantiate a MetaCoin "object" that points to the deployed address by doing `MetaCoin(DeployedAddresses.MetaCoin())`. Simply doing `DeployedAddresses.MetaCoin()` will give you the address the contract is deployed to but won't give you the ability to make any calls or transactions.

Comment: So MetaCoin as it appears before the "meta" variable is like a modified "var"? I'm understanding it to mean "var in the context of the metacoin contract".